# Random sort for SimplePie

Tags: simplepie

I'm looking specifically to randomly sort all SimplePie articles from a default installation.  (no WordPress attachments or anything)

I'm not looking for any custom sorting options, just a completely random sort of the items and nothing else.

Looking to set this up for a simple page.  The only examples i've found so far are the ones that display the php coding near the top, but do not show how to call out those features in html.

Example : Do separate classes need to be created ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the standard PHP `shuffle` function?
http://php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php

Provided you store all the items fetched by SimplePie in an array, I think this is the shortest way to get them randomly sorted.

Comment: it appears SimplePie recommends the sort_items() tag as they explain here -  http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/sort_items  .   But I still can't get to work.

Comment: The coding that i'm currently using...that works for standard sort, but not random sort -<?php
require_once('./simplepie/autoloader.php');

// Set your own configuration options as you see fit.
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url(array(
 'http://feeds.energydigger.com/conventional-energy/oil-and-natural-gas.xml',
));
$feed->set_cache_duration(300);
$success = $feed->init();

Comment: ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Oil Gas Prices</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projector" />
 
</head>
 
<body>
<h1>Oil Gas Prices</h1>

Comment: <div id="site">
 <?php
 // If we have an error, display it.
 if ($feed->error())
 {
  echo '<div class="sp_errors">' . "\r\n";
  echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($feed->error()) . "</p>\r\n";
  echo '</div>' . "\r\n";
 }
 ?>

Comment: <?php if ($success): ?>
  <?php
  // get_items() will accept values from above.
  foreach($feed->get_items($start, $length) as $item):
   $feed = $item->get_feed();
  ?>
 
   <div class="chunk">
 
    <h2><?php if ($item->get_permalink()) echo '<a href="' . $item->get_permalink() . '" target="_blank">'; echo $item->get_title(true); if ($item->get_permalink()) echo '</a>'; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $item->get_content(); ?> <br />
                           <?php echo $item->get_date('j M Y | g:i a T'); ?><br />
    

   </div>
 
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

Comment: also, sorry for the unprofessional coding sort above.  2nd time posting here.  Any help with posting 'code' directly in the future here is appreciated.

Comment: Dont worry for the code :-) I dont know if comments really can contain `newline` or things like that. I understand that SimplePIE recommends using sort_items() but you really want exactly the opposite: un-sort them. So unless they offer a possible value to "sort by" like `sort_items('random')` I dont see any other exit than falling back to the randomize function of your choice. As you mentioned WordPress I assumed you are familiar with PHP, that's why I recommended shuffle. Is there any documentation of possible input values for sort_items()?

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  What do you recommend I shuffle $feed or $item ?   shuffle( $item );  or shuffle( $feed );    thanks.

Comment: I think I would fetch all the items I need (ie. 2 items per feed) and then shuffle the pool of items just before printing it on screen :)